# What's the PHP $_SERVER variable for the directory above DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Tags: php, variables

I have a server where the public root is located at: `/var/www/example.com/html/`.

Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` I get the following result:

```
/var/www/example.com/html/
```

What `$_SERVER` array key would I use to get the path directly above the public root? That is, the one here:

```
/var/www/example.com/
```

This will have to work on multiple environments, such as local and live. Not sure if there's some way of doing `./` document_root sort of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`dirname()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) returns the parent directory of a directory and is platform independent.

```
dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Should return:

```
/var/www/example.com
```

If you need the trailing slash then you can append `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`:

```
dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: Be carefull with dirname on DOCUMENT_ROOT. If your docroot does _not_ have an trailing slash, e.g. `/var/www/example.com`, dirname would change this into `/var/www`!

Answer (score 0):

../ is the unixey way to say the folder above so, for example, in a terminal these are the same thing:
/home/user/
/home/user/heavymark/../

If OTOH you need support for Windows directory naming you will have to do the work of removing the last bit of the path. Normally you might do this by using a regular expression to capture all but the last filepathbit/ but to support Windows naming you have to fancy it up to handle both filepathbit/ and filepathbit.